# � in Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, json

I´m trying to load a json-file on my localhost. The file looks like:

```
{
 "0": {
  "file": {
    "This is something - else": "abz"
  }
 }
}
```

So when I load this  file the - will replaced to � (saw in Firefox Debugger). The interesting thing is, that I have a lot of more items (0-11) and the error appears only on this element.

Can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong? 
I have specified in the ajax request explicitly utf8

Comment: You've probably got a `-` symbol from a different character set.

Comment: There's a hyphen and then there's a dash.  A dash is a special character whereas a hyphen is what you can type on your keyboard.  Unless your file is UTF-8 encoded, the dash is likely to show up as you've displayed here.

Comment: You´re right. 
but how can that be? 
it is a hyphen, thought this is every time the same

Comment: What is the different between dash and hyphen?

Comment: If your file is using UTF-8 encoding, add the `Content-Type: <whatever>; charset=utf-8` header.

Comment: @SalmanA the problem is already solved. I don´t know why but I had to replace the hyphen with a new hyphen and the problem was solved. Can somebody explain to me what the difference between hyphen and dash is?

Comment: probably you copied that "hyphen" from another source and that copied "hyphen" was encoded differently.